# Adding a element to an existing struct in a Spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe and the schema looks like this:

```
root
|-- useragent: string (nullable = true)
|-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- browser: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- device: string (nullable = true)
```

I am using `udf` + `withColumn` to extract more info out of the useragent. But I am only able to store any additional property I am creating in a new column. Is there a way I can append it to the struct itself?

I've changed the schema but it doesn't transfer all the data I needed from the other properties that already exist

```
df = df.schema['properties'].dataType.add(StructField('type', StringType()))
```

Would it make more sense to convert this to a RDD?

Answer (score 1):

[**`withField`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html#pyspark.sql.Column.withField) can be used:

```py
F.col("properties").withField("type", extract_function)
```

---

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("type=type1,mode=5", ("Chrome", "PC1"))],
    "useragent string, properties struct<browser:string,device:string>"
)
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- useragent: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- browser: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- device: string (nullable = true)
df.show()
# +-----------------+-------------+
# |        useragent|   properties|
# +-----------------+-------------+
# |type=type1,mode=5|{Chrome, PC1}|
# +-----------------+-------------+

df = df.withColumn("properties", F.col("properties").withField(
    "type",
    F.regexp_extract("useragent", r"type=(\w+)", 1)
))

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- useragent: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- browser: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- device: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
df.show()
# +-----------------+--------------------+
# |        useragent|          properties|
# +-----------------+--------------------+
# |type=type1,mode=5|{Chrome, PC1, type1}|
# +-----------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not get any data using this piece of code, since you are not selecting any data.
What you are doing in this operation is nothing but accessing the `Schema` property, modifying it in some way and assigning it to a variable `df` (this is not the modified dataframe you are expecting) but just a StructType object (There seems to be some syntax error there, please check)

What you should do is to modify the dataframe through `select` and suitable transformation functions. You may considering creating a new column of type `StructField` with the required structure and add it as a new column using `withColumn` function